# tiny mce style_formats title

Tags: tinymce

i'm using tinymce style_formats like this:

```
style_formats : [
                {title : '20px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '20px'}},
                {title : '25px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '25px'}},
                {title : '30px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '30px'}},
                {title : '35px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '35px'}},
                {title : '40px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '40px'}},
                {title : '45px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '45px'}},
                {title : '50px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '50px'}},
                {title : '55px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '55px'}},
                {title : '60px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '60px'}},
                {title : '65px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '65px'}},
                {title : '70px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '70px'}},
                {title : '75px', selector : 'p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', styles: {lineHeight: '75px'}}
        ]
    });
```

The title of the listbox is "Styles" i want to change it to "Line Height".

Where I need to change? I can't find it in the lang files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open **tinymce-->themes-->advanced-->lang-->en.js**

Change **"style_select":"Styles"** to **"style_select":"Line Height"**

Hope it helps!!

NOTE: You will have to keep this change in mind whenever you update tinymce to a new version

Answer (score 1):

To change the title can modify the lang files under `tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/en.js`
like "Display Name" described.

But to avoid to have to modify this file everytime you update to a new tinymce version you may change the title using the oninit and setup tinymce configuration parameter in tinymce.init:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.i18n['en.advanced.style_select'] = 'Line Height';
```

So, you could use:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
     ed.onBeforeRenderUI.add(function(ed, cm) {
         tinymce.EditorManager.i18n['en.advanced.style_select'] = 'Line Height';
     });
   }
});
```