# Change style_formats title - TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am new to TinyMCE but have done most of my required work.
I am stuck at one place. I want to change the title of the dropdown which comes by "style_formats". The current title it is showing is "Formats". I want to make it like WordPress Panel. I mean if i select "paragraph" from the drop down, it must shows paragraph, if i select "Heading 1" from the drop down, the title must be changed to "Heading 1" and so on.

I have already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922136/tiny-mce-style-formats-title) but it was not that much useful

Note: I am using TinyMCE 4

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box.
For this you will have to write an own plugin that takes care of this.
You may want to have a look at the tinymce source file FormatControls.js .

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **listbox**, this is not exactly an answer, but it will help your cause, I'm not sure, how you are going to mix it up with `Formats`(style_formats), check the [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/LIdaab) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602764/how-to-add-tinymce-listbox-values-in-windowmanager), you get an idea of listbox.

You can add `listbox` in `menubar` of `tinymce` editor .